# 2 function calls into onChange - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna that into an OnChange, this event calls to 2 different functions with ReactJS. I have tried several forms but I have not success. I have tried:

```
/*This is my text area, into ONCHANGE I put options shown below*/
<textarea name="NAME" id="ID" ONCHANGE placeholder="PLACEHOLDER" maxLength="4000" rows="7" class="form-control" required></textarea> 

/*This way give me error*/
onChange={this.activarBotonEnviar this.contadorDeCaracteres}

/*This way give me error*/
onChange={this.activarBotonEnviar; this.contadorDeCaracteres}

/*This way only execute last function*/
onChange={this.activarBotonEnviar, this.contadorDeCaracteres}

/*This way only execute last function*/
onChange={this.activarBotonEnviar} onChange={this.contadorDeCaracteres}
```

I am working with ReactJS. I hope you could help me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How it is possible for a variable/property to hold two values at the same time?

We can assign a single function to Onchange event, so what you can do is either create a new function and call these two function from that or call one from another.

Creating new Function:

```
onChange = { (e) => { this.activarBotonEnviar(e); this.contadorDeCaracteres(e) } }
```

Calling one function from another:

```
onChange = { this.activarBotonEnviar }
```

and call `contadorDeCaracteres` from `activarBotonEnviar` function:

```
activarBotonEnviar(e){
   ...
   this.activarBotonEnviar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`onChange={this.myFunc}`

```
myFunc(){
    this.activarBotonEnviar();
    this.contadorDeCaracteres();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a good idea, I think that too. But I wanna do it into onchange all. Without need other function that calls both. :D

Comment: So, another variant will help you :)